# touchevents not triggering from inside subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, event-handling, uiimageview

I'm having my share of trouble trying to get a touch event through a UIView to it's attached childviews.

I have a number of images I want to do various things with, so I'm interested in reading the touch events on them. It worked fine until I decided to group them in a UIView, so I'm guessing I need to switch some setting on or off to let the events through.

```
[TouchImageView.h] -------------------------------------------------------

@interface TouchImageView : UIImageView

[TouchImageView.m] -------------------------------------------------------

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]) {
        // We set it here directly for convenience
        // As by default for a UIImageView it is set to NO
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        state = 0 ;
        rect = aRect ;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Do what you want here
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan!" );
}

[in my delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions] -------------------------

NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"front-photos.jpg"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"front-films.jpg"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"front-presentations.jpg"],

mainMenuView = [[UIView alloc] init ] ;
mainMenuView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;    // tried setting this to both YES and NO. Same result.
[self.viewController.view addSubview:mainMenuView] ;

myImage = [[TouchImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, menuTopHeight, menuButtonWidth, menuButtonHeight)];
[myImage setImage:[myImages objectAtIndex:0]] ;
[mainMenuView addSubview:myImage] ;
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've seen a lot of similar posts here on SO on this topic, but most of them about setting userInteractionEnabled(?)

Comment: why don't you use UIGesturerecognizer

Comment: @AlbrahimZ I didn't know one was better than the other(?). Figured that overloading touchesBegan would be the simplest solution. Didn't expect it to not work. I'm not that familiar with UIGesturerecognizer - What makes it a better option?

Comment: Gesture recoginizers are for high level gestures so they behave the same with all  apps. For low level control and to do things that the recognizers can't you will still have to implement logic in touchesbegan, touchesEnded, etc.

Comment: so, you're telling me if I replace touchesBegin wiht a gesture recognizer, then it won't be blocked by being in a sub view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to define a frame for the UIView. So I changed

```
mainMenuView = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
```

into this:

```
mainMenuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] ;
```

and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `mainMenuView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` should be `YES`
Also `UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO by deafult, so you will have to set it to YES

After this line

```
[mainMenuView addSubview:myImage] ;
//add
myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I set it to YES in its constructor. With regards to mainMenuView - I've tried with both YES and NO, it works neither way.

Comment: sorry i didnt notice them, what are the values for menuTopHeight, menuButtonWidth, menuButtonHeight?

Comment: the values are just the dimensions of the image, for the sake of the example they could be defined as 0,0,200,200 - as I mentioned to start out with, the events work fine until i put add them to the mainMenuView instead of the self.viewcontroller.view view.

Comment: what is the frame of mainMenuView?

Comment: It didn't have a frame - and apparently it was what caused it to not trigger. Once I changed my code to init with rect, it started working - Thanks!